# How to add two table views in one UIviewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have created a page where i need to use two table views for adding dynamic options. The problem is that only one table is displaying its data and the other one is not. Am totally confused where did i do wrong.

screen shot of my views.

[image]

[image]

Below am adding my code-

```
@interface FlirtMatchViewController ()
{
    UILabel *headerTitle;
    NSArray *tableData;
    NSArray *arrimages;
    NSArray *tableData1;
    NSArray *arrimages1;  
}
@end

@implementation FlirtMatchViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    tableData = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"TattooSingles",@"Eyecatcher",@"Tattoo Toplist",@"Radar",@"Flirt Chat",@"Free VIP Membership",@"VIP Membership",@"Invite Friends",nil];

    arrimages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"tatto_single@2x.png",@"eye_catcher.png",@"tatto_toplist.png",@"radar.png",@"Flirt_chat.png",@"free_vip.png",@"vip_membership_navigation.png",@"add-friend1.png", nil];

    tableData1 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"TattooSingles",@"Eyecatcher",@"Tattoo Toplist",@"Radar",@"Flirt Chat",@"Free VIP Membership",@"VIP Membership",@"Invite Friends",nil];

    arrimages1 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"tatto_single@2x.png",@"eye_catcher.png",@"tatto_toplist.png",@"radar.png",@"Flirt_chat.png",@"free_vip.png",@"vip_membership_navigation.png",@"add-friend1.png", nil];
 }

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(tableView==_leftTableView)
    {
        return [tableData count];
    }
    else {
        return [tableData1 count];
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier2 = @"Cell2";
    static NSString *CellIdentifier1 = @"Cell1";

    if(tableView==self.leftTableView)
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier1 = @"Cell1";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier1];
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier1] ;
        }

        cell.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        return cell;
    }
    else
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier2 = @"Cell2";

        UITableViewCell *cell1 = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier2];
        if (cell1 == nil)
        {
            cell1= [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier2] ;
        }

        cell1.textLabel.text = [tableData1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        return cell1;
    }

}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    TattooSinglesScreen *obj=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TattooSinglesScreen"];
    EyecatcherScreen *obj1=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"EyecatcherScreen"];
    TattooToplist *obj2=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TattooToplist"];

    int i=indexPath.row;

    if(i==0){
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:NO];
    }
    else if (i==1) {
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:obj1 animated:NO];
    }
    else if (i==2) {
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:obj2 animated:NO];
    }

}
```

Also am trying to navigate the first three options to their particular screen by using the code below. But the code is not working for me. Can anyone clear my doubts?

Comment: whats your second tableview name

Comment: Are you missing to add `if(tableView==self.leftTableView)` in didSelect as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do like

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
if (tableView == self. leftTableView)
{
    return [tableData count];
}

if (tableView == self. rightTableView)
{
    return [tableData1 count];
}


}


-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{    
if(tableView==self.leftTableView)
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier1 = @"Cell1";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier1];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier1] ;
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

if (tableView == self._rightTableView)
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier2 = @"Cell2";

    UITableViewCell *cell1 = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier2];
    if (cell1 == nil)
    {
        cell1= [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier2] ;
    }

    cell1.textLabel.text = [tableData1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell1;
}

}
```

Comment: can you update the quetiuon once, at the same time check once are you given the connection of `_rightTableView` datasource and delegate to currnet viewcontroller

Comment: sorry i did some really stupid mistake sir...thats why it  did'nt worked that time....now its working fine....thanks alot!!!

Comment: @priyasharma - initially it happens dont feel, happy to hear, plz give the tick mark for the answer .

Answer (score 1):

What Anbu suggested will work, although could I suggest you create separate classses to handle the datasource and delegate for each UITableView, then simply assign the datasource and delegate to your new classes for each tableview. This will be cleaner and might help resolve the logic issues you have.

Hope this helps, comment if you have any questions, good luck.

Comment: i will do exactly as you have suggested. Thanks!!